# Disable input from laptop keyboard input

Tags: keyboard, 20.04, dell, input-devices, shortcut-keys

I am getting random input of the **up** key causing browser and other application causing unintended scrolling.

I have disabled up **up** key from from `xmodmap`:

```
$ xmodmap -pke  |  grep -i up 
keycode  80 = KP_Up KP_8 KP_Up KP_8
keycode 133 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
keycode 134 = Super_R NoSymbol Super_R
keycode 151 = XF86WakeUp NoSymbol XF86WakeUp
keycode 206 = NoSymbol Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
keycode 233 = XF86MonBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessUp
keycode 238 = XF86KbdBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86KbdBrightnessUp
```

```
$uname -a
Linux renegade 5.4.0-26-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 20 16:58:30 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I captured input using `sudo evtest` and I can see input value with scan code `c8`  multiple times within seconds.  How can i disable this input.

I am using a Dell laptop.

```
Event: time 1596356833.698079, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value c8
Event: time 1596356833.698079, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 103 (KEY_UP), value 2
Event: time 1596356833.698079, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1596356833.729516, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value c8
Event: time 1596356833.729516, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 103 (KEY_UP), value 2
Event: time 1596356833.729516, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1596356833.758025, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value c8
Event: time 1596356833.758025, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 103 (KEY_UP), value 2
Event: time 1596356833.758025, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1596356833.789753, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value c8
Event: time 1596356833.789753, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 103 (KEY_UP), value 2
Event: time 1596356833.789753, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1596356833.822339, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value c8
Event: time 1596356833.822339, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 103 (KEY_UP), value 2
Event: time 1596356833.822339, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1596356833.853520, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value c8
Event: time 1596356833.853520, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 103 (KEY_UP), value 2
Event: time 1596356833.853520, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1596356833.885129, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value c8
Event: time 1596356833.885129, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 103 (KEY_UP), value 2
Event: time 1596356833.885129, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

Comment: You still have `KP_Up` (the keypad up arrow) enabled. Try to disable it too.